# Alter table column from select statement

Tags: select, teradata, alter

Was wondering if this is possible in Teradata, see below example (not actual data).

```
drop table TCC
/
create multiset volatile table TCC, no log
( TableName varchar(255)  not null
, C1        varchar(255)  not null
)
unique primary index (TableName)
on commit preserve rows;
/
insert into TCC values ('TableName','ColumnName');
/
Alter table (select TableName from TCC) ADD (select C1 from TCC) VARCHAR(5000) 
CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC FORMAT 'X(5000)';
```

This is the error I keep getting...

[Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.10.00.26] [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something    like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier between '(' and the 'select' keyword.

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Expecting table and column name to feed into alter statement from select statements.  Missing some unicode and I don't know what is missing.

Comment: You can't embed a SELECT in a DDL statement, nor can name tokens be supplied via parameter substitution. You will need to substitute the actual names in the request text, either on the client side or as "dynamic SQL" in a stored procedure.